How to start/cancel commands activated by autocmd that are run often without having multiple processes?
Currently, I have an AutoCmd that runs a build command every time any file of a certain filetype is saved. However, the command is run such that it is forked from the nvim process (ie, something like vim.cmd([build &])). This normally works fine --- however, if I save my file before the last command finishes (which can happen, as the build process is fairly slow), now I have two separate processes running on the same file, which is not ideal. So, is there a way to set up my Autocmd such that if a build process (B) is triggered while one (A) is already running, A is first cancelled, and only then B is allowed to run?
As I am using Neovim, I would prefer a solution that uses Nvim-native functionality; however, if a more "elegant" solution can be done using raw Vimscript, then that would be appreciated. There may be a package (either for nvim or vim) that wraps it nicely, but I couldn't find any in my searches (maybe I don't know the right keywords).
Right now, my AutoCmd looks like
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufWritePost"}, {
    pattern = {"*.ext"},
    callback = function(ev)
       vim.cmd([[silent exec "build_cmd &"]])
        end
    end


Are you using shell job-control or (Neo)Vim jobs? (See :help job, probably.) It would probably help answerers see how you actually start the jobs (please [edit]).

@D.BenKnoble I already mentioned I just use raw vim.cmd without any job control. I'll edit that to be more explicit.

Look into vim.system(), you can pass { detach = true } in opts and you can pass it an on_exit argument with a function to call when it finishes, you can also call :wait() on the returned object, or :kill() to interrupt it

@filbranden I was able to look into this again, and with that hint, got a system set up with vim.system. However, I found that if the parent nvim quits, the processes are still open. Is there a an option to force the children to exit when the parent does?
